# JavaScript logger into a rolling file

Tags: javascript, logging

i've a JavaScript application.

I'd like to use a logger but instead of logging to a console (like Firebug or Yahoo UI), I'd like to log to a file or several files.

Ideally, It should be possible to back up the files when they reach a certain limit.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing to a file on the client machine is not generally possible via JavaScript running in a web page. It can be done in IE using ActiveX (when the user has allowed it) and I think also in Firefox when the user has enabled an obscure setting, but is generally not possible. There are various questions about this in Stack Overflow. For example:

- [Is it possible to write to a file (on a disk) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461791/can-you-write-to-a-file-on-a-disk-in-javascript)
- [Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/jquery-read-write-to-file)

Bearing that in mind, it has never seemed worthwhile implementing a local file appender in [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/). If you do want to log to a file, I would suggest using the [AjaxAppender](http://log4javascript.org/docs/manual.html#ajaxappender) to send log messages to the server and log those messages to log4j / log4net / log4php / whatever set up with a rolling file appender.

Comment: +1... Good idea about the AjaxAppender and log4x mix... By the way, kudos for log4javascript :)

Comment: I've read an article about the AjaxAppender to send messages, it seems to be a good idea. However, I don't want to send messages over the network again and again. There's a FileAppender in Log4Js (i haven't tested it though), but no rollingFile. Maybe I should try using the ActiveX ..

Comment: FileAppender in log4js uses ActiveX in IE and built-in code in Firefox that requires the user to have enabled a setting. If this is a reasonable solution for you then I'd suggest using it. It shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to do the RollingFileAppender stuff. Otherwise, AjaxAppender in log4javascript does allow you to send log messages in batches of a particular size or at particular timed intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [log4js](http://log4js.berlios.de/). It is a logging API based on the popular [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) framework. It is an open source project, using the Apache License 2.0.

You may also want to check out the [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) project, written by the Stack Overflow regular [@Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down).

Comment: @LB: No there doesn't seem to be one.