# Write file to disk

Tags: javascript, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write to a file (on a disk) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461791/is-it-possible-to-write-to-a-file-on-a-disk-using-javascript)

Is it possible to write file to file system, say `C:\myfile\myfile.bin` using Javascript?

I have this function:

```
var data = MyObject.getdata(); // typeof data = "object"
```

And I want to write "data" to a file for debugging purposes.

Comment: Short answer is ***no***

Comment: The console in chrome and ff offers really nice debugging tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but you can use new Local storage on HTML5 -

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", Data);
```

Comment: This will, in all probability, **not** write a file to the filesystem. In most browsers, it will merely create a row in a SQLite database.

Comment: So what? It's impossible to do what he asked for, so Dor is providing a perfectly valid, portable alternative. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question, which should be "No, but..." and maybe list how to access the data afterwards (since that's obviously required).

Answer (score 2):

You can write file to the filesystem throw ActiveX, but it works only on Windows and only on IE.