# Writing to .txt file within html NO DOWNLOAD

Tags: javascript, html, save

Please tell me whats wrong with my code !!!! im trying to get a text areas contents and save it into a existing text file

```
<textarea rows='10' cols='80' id='passForm' ></textarea>
<button onclick="WriteToFile()">Post</button>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function WriteToFile(passForm) {

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
set s = fso.CreateTextFile("E:/MyStuff/test.txt", True);
s.writeline(document.passForm.input1.value);
s.Close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry to say this but it is not possible to save a file to disk using jscript.
This question is already answered at [Write file to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503112/write-file-to-disk) . the answer says that it is not possible. but you can use local storage