# JS - saving uploaded file do disc

Tags: javascript, html

I have this file input

```
<input type="file" class="file-input">
```

which I am using to upload images in my project.

How can I save the uploaded image to certain local folder with JS ?

Comment: This can't be done. But, you could use javascript to pass the file to a server side endpoint to save it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461791/is-it-possible-to-write-to-a-file-on-a-disk-using-javascript

Comment: @user2079802 if he using node.js - he can

Comment: @Legendary I think it's safe to assume he's not

Comment: @user2079802 me either, but dont being so overconfident ever ;)

Comment: Yes, can't be done with JUST JS.  But if you add in a language like PHP, ASP or Node then yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to save the files locally, you can use the HTML5 [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) feature. Its a fairly simple technology to store key/value pairs inside the browser storage. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) suggests, I prefer using the Web Storage API. For storing the image, a solution can be:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var thisImage = reader.result;
        localStorage.setItem("imgData", thisImage);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Here's a demo storing an image from an  element, storing the image inside the local storage and showing it back.
http://jsfiddle.net/touhid91/nmy2b9j4/

Comment: what is localStorage..? @touhid'